# Filling data in FormView from different tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, formview

I am using a FormView in an online quiz page for displaying the questions and RadioButtons (for answers)

> [online quiz using ASP dot NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438219/online-quiz-using-asp-dot-net)

Now, I need to pick the questions according to a TestID and a particular Set of that Test. The testid and the set_number would be passed using Session variables.
I'm having 3 testIDs and 3 Sets per TestID and, thus, am using 9 tables to store the Questions, the Options and the correct answer.

I need help on how to set the FormView so that it extracts the questions from a particular table only. Do I need to use a StoredProcedure ? If yes, how?

PS: If I use only one table to store all the questions from each Set and for each TestID, I can do that, but I'd prefer using separate tables.

**Update**

SOLVED myself

[CLOSED]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `view` for gathering data from your tables. then query this view and use the returned data.